# plot::plim: Range specification message missing in 11.0.1

Tags: plotting, bugs, warning-messages

**Bug introduced in 11.0.1 and fixed in 11.1.0**

---

In version 11.0.1, the error message  `Plot::pllim: Range specification` no longer shows up when a user makes an error. And no beep either.

Example:

```
r = 2;
Plot[Exp[-x], {-r, r}]
```

Here is the above command run on 10.4 and on 11.0.1, both on windows, 64 bit:

### Version 10.4

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Version 11.0.1

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I do not have version 11.0 installed any more, as 11.0.1 replaced it, so I can't check when this difference came about.

Should this be tagged a bug?

Comment: Version 11 still has the error message.

Comment: I tagged as bug. I can confirm it.

Comment: With version 11.0.0 on Win7 x64 I get the error message.

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been fixed as of Mathematica 11.1.0.

```
r = 2;

Plot[Exp[-x], {-r, r}]
```

> Plot::pllim: Range specification {-2, 2} is not of the form {x, xmin, xmax}.

```
(* Plot[Exp[-x], {-r, r}] *)
```